# Flutter ".Where" Filter Doesn't Update When Pressing Backspace

Tags: android, ios, flutter, listview

I'm currently trying to build a search window that filters through countries.

```
TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _countrySearchQuery = value;
                          _countryCodes = _countryCodes.where((element) =>
                              element.name.toLowerCase().contains(_countrySearchQuery.toLowerCase())
                          ).toList();
                        });
                        print(_countrySearchQuery);
                        print(_countryCodes);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
```

it seems to work fine until I press backspace (which should display more list values as the search becomes more broader) but it seems to continue adding onto the existing query (narrowing the search even more) without resetting it.

If I type "kingdo" for United Kingdom
then press backspace to "king" it doesn't update based on "king" it still seems to stay on "kingdo" and keep appending onto it until the list returns nothing.

The print statements show that the search query is returning exactly what has been typed in so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Your `onChanged` callback sets `_countryCodes = _countryCodes.where(...).toList()` on every change.  Therefore `_countryCodes` can only become smaller and never larger.  You instead will need to maintain a copy of the original list and filter against that.

Comment: As the comment above, change _countryCodes to be other var instead. don't assign it back to their own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer creating different list for result.

```
class TestCenter extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestCenter({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestCenterState createState() => _TestCenterState();
}

class _TestCenterState extends State<TestCenter> {
  String _countrySearchQuery = "";

  List<String> _countryCodes =
      List.generate(10, (index) => "$index${index * 2}");

  List<String> matches = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text("data: ${_countryCodes.toString()}"),
          TextFormField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(
                () {
                  _countrySearchQuery = value;
                  matches = _countryCodes
                      .where((element) => element
                          .toLowerCase()
                          .contains(_countrySearchQuery.toLowerCase()))
                      .toList();
                },
              );

              print("countryCode:  $_countryCodes");
              print("match: $matches");
            },
          ),
          Text(_countrySearchQuery.length > 0
              ? matches.length > 0
                  ? matches.toString()
                  : "could not found"
              : "start typing")
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```